# How to make a deep copy Dictionary template

Tags: c#, .net, templates, dictionary

I have the following method that makes a `deep copy` of a dictionary:

```
public static Dictionary<string, MyClass> deepCopyDic(Dictionary<string, MyClass> src)
{
    //Copies a dictionary with all of its elements
    //RETURN:
    //      = Dictionary copy
    Dictionary<string, MyClass> dic = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.Count; i++)
    {
        dic.Add(src.ElementAt(i).Key, new MyClass(src.ElementAt(i).Value));
    }

    return dic;
}
```

I was wondering, can I somehow make it into a template? I need `MyClass` to be a template.

Comment: ... a template for what?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: For `MyClass` to be `MyOtherClass` or `MyAnotherClass`, etc.

Comment: you mean an abstract class?  An interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Generics with `where TValue : ICloneable` constraint:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> deepCopyDic<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> src)
    where TValue : ICloneable
{
    //Copies a dictionary with all of its elements
    //RETURN:
    //      = Dictionary copy
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dic = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    foreach (var item in src)
    {
        dic.Add(item.Key, (TValue)item.Value.Clone());
    }

    return dic;
}
```

You'll have to implement [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) interface in every class you'd like to pass into that method.

Or a bit improved version, with `Key` cloned as well:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> deepCopyDic<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> src)
    where TValue : ICloneable
    where TKey : ICloneable
{
    return src.ToDictionary(i => (TKey)i.Key.Clone(), i => (TValue)i.Value.Clone());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was missing :)

Comment: So instead of `ICloneable` can I just copy it with the `new` and the constructor?

Comment: No, you can't because you can't set generic constraint like `where TValue : new(TValue)`

Comment: OK. So now I need to somehow find a way to add that `ICloneable` to `MyClass`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek No not silent downvoters. it's me. I was just writing comment for OP.

Comment: @ahmd0 Just call your existing constructor `return new MyClass(this)` within `Clone` method.

Comment: You don't iterate a dictionary with a `for` loop.  That's pure badness.  It is, by design, unordered.  You should use a `foreach` loop to iterate the dictionary.  It will perform better (O(n) rather than O(n^2) and actually have predictable results (which is much more important)).  With your code you can't even be sure that each key in the new dictionary is paired with the same value that was in the old dictionary.

Comment: @Servy You're right! I just copied existing loop from question sample.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek You also aren't cloning the key.  `TKey` should implement `ICloneable` and be cloned as well.  You can also use `ToDictionary` to simplify the code, so long as you clone the key/value in each selector.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I agree `foreach` looks better in C#, but still what do you think it does on the inside -- it copies these elements one by one too.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: In case of cloning and your second method, what if the key is something like `Guid` that doesn't support that `ICloneable`?

Comment: @ahmd0 Sure.  That's not a problem at all.  Do you realize what the your code does?  For each iteration of the `for` loop it creates a new iterator, that iterator will iterate through each of the n-1 previous elements to get the nth element, and that's done for both the key and the value.  On top of that, it makes the assertion that the items returned in the enumeration for a dictionary are always in the same order (given that it enumerates it 2*n times).  **That's a false assumption**.  A dictionary is not an ordered collection; it can return them in an entirely different order each time!

Comment: @ahmd0 Then it wouldn't compile and you'd need to either pass in a delegate to handle the cloning, or wrap the object in something that *is* capable of cloning itself (in a meaningful way).  If that can't be done, then you won't be able to clone the dictionary.  Some thing simply can't be cloned, there's no way around that.  At the very least this method won't make you think you can clone it when you really can't.

Comment: @Servy: My goal is not to clone but to copy all elements from one dictionary to another (I think it's called `deep copy`).

Comment: @ahmd0 And I'm telling you that your code to iterate the dictionary is *very broken*, even before you do anything with it. Next, a copy isn't just deep or shallow, it's more complex than that.  It's a sliding scale.  You could copy a reference to the dictionary.  You could create a new dictionary but just copy the references to items in it.  You could create a new dictionary and new items, but copy references of items inside those items, etc. A "deep copy" implies going all the way to the lowest level, not stopping at some earlier point.

Comment: @ahmd0 Now it may be perfectly appropriate for you to create a new dictionary, but then just perform a shallow copy of the elements of that dictionary.  In many actual uses cases this is appropriate functionality.  It's not really a "deep copy" (although I would avoid using that term in general; it's often ambiguous).  If that's what you want then [this earlier version of another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15956435/1) is actually the correct one.

Comment: @Servy: OK. I do need to copy **everything** from one dictionary to another. Can you show how?

Comment: @ahmd0 You've now made your statement even more ambiguous than it was before.  Do you want to create a new dictionary, but create a shallow copy of all of the items in that dictionary?  If so, see the link I added as an edit to my previous comment.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not sure why you don't understand me. I have one dictionary. I need to create its copy where all elements are copied without any references, or any connections to the first dictionary. In other words it must be a totally separate dictionary.

Comment: @I4V: It may very well work, but I'd prefer not to use any third-party libraries or extensions for something as simple as copying a dictionary.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not sure what was the point of all the polemic above, only to leave me hanging???

Comment: @ahmd0 `but I'd prefer not to use any third-party libraries or extensions for something as simple as copying a dictionary` it is not as simple as you think when it comes to **deep-copy**. Otherwise you would have accepted the first version of the answer. FYI: you can use other built-in serializers like JavaScriptSerializer, BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter, XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer etc.

Comment: @ahmd0 `only to leave me hanging?` After so many answers/comments i still don't know what you are *really* want to do. Don't you think I may be a problem with you. Or what do you understand from *copying a dictionary*?.

Comment: @I4V: "I have one dictionary. I need to create its copy where all elements are copied without any references, or any connections to the first dictionary. In other words it must be a totally separate dictionary." -- how else shall I describe it?????

Comment: @ahmd0 I said hours ago. *use serialization*, Any serializer that suits to your needs. What is so hard to understand?

Comment: @I4V, I'm relatively new to this managed code concept. Saying that I need to use _serialization_ has as much meaning to me as "flying a pink elephant" ...

Comment: @ahmd0 and I gave an answer for dummies. Either use it or try with other serializers.

Comment: @ahmd0 If only there was some place where you could go to get information about virtually anything, let's call this made up place "Google".  Going to such a place might allow you to enter a word, say "serialization", perhaps with some additional context, say "serialization C#" and instantly get millions of references to detailed and reputable sources describing what the concept was, and how you could go about using it.  Wouldn't the mythical world containing such a marvelous tool be wonderful.

Comment: @ahmd0 -1? OK. I will remove my answer, but your question will be here forever :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the copy constructor option:

```
Dictionary<string, int> copy = new Dictionary<string, int>(dictionary);
```

This way you make a deep copy of your dictionary.
[Link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/copy-dictionary) to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

The Serialized approach is the only way as noted above. ICloneable does not guarantee that all properties in the object being clone is not assigning references unless you have full control over the object which is never a good assumption, especially in a large team.

The only cavet of the Serialized approach is that all objects being passed in the dictionary are serializable. Also, serializing is not always very efficient because of the over use of Reflection that occurs, which shouldn't be used in high preformance areas of code.

I solved this problem using an approach known as fast serialization but it requires that all objects that you plan to clone support a specific interface.  It's always speed vs. complexity.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. Dictionaries are not Serializable. So, if you plan to use the Serializable technique, you would need to iterate all your objects in the Dictionary.