# How to deep copy a Dictionary containing a List in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to a make a deep copy of a `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`. I tried:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> tmpStudents =
   new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(students);
```

but manipulating the values in `tmpStudents` is still changing those in `students`. It seems that the lists in `tmpStudents` are still referencing the lists in `students`, but I'm not sure how to remedy this without manually deep copying each list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956352/how-to-make-a-deep-copy-dictionary-template?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to deep-copy the lists as well; all you have done is copy the dictionary, but all of the list references are still shared between them.

This is fairly easy using LINQ:

```
var tmpStudents = students.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value.ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var tmpStudents = students.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToList());
```

Because you have a `List<int>` and `int` is a value type this should work. Otherwise you have to create a deep copy for each value separately.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your `Dictionary` to a `MemoryStream` using a `BinaryFormatter`, and then deserialize it back to your variable:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
   IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
   formatter.Serialize(ms, oldStudants);
   var newStudants = (Dictionary<String, List<int>>)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
}
```